# addSubview with NSObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, uiview, nsobject

I have a class which is an NSObject type, and in a view it won't let me put:

```
[self.view addSubview:nsObject];
```

because it's an incompatible type. How can i get this to work?

Comment: why are you trying to add a non UIView object as a subview to a UIView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the object you're adding to be of the type `UIView` or inherit from it.  In your class declaration, simply put:

```
@interface MyClasS : UIView {
```

Comment: The problem here is that it then won't let me do anything else to it that I want to do. I want it to be it's own object, but I also want it to show in my main view.

Comment: What kind of stuff are you trying to do to it that you cant by subclassing UIView?

Comment: Oh, i was wrong. It's because i tried making it a UIView originally and for some reason that wasn't working, but making a new one as an NSObject worked, and changing that to say UIView also works.

Answer (score 4):

The `addSubview:` method only takes instances of `UIView`. It won't work with `NSObject`.

Check out the method specification in the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that nsSubview is a subclass of UIView and just by typing, arg passing the compiler is seeing it as an NSObject?  Or is it some kind of wrapper object that contains a UIView?  You could try:

```
UIView *v = (UIView *)nsSubview ;
[ self.view addSubview:v] ;
```

Comment: C-style casts are dangerous, unless you are CERTAIN that the pointers are the correct type youre converting them to

Comment: There is never a case where that cast should be necessary.  It is impossible to plug a non-UIView subclass into a view as a subview and have any hope that it'll work correctly.  Polymorphism can only reasonably do so much.

Comment: (sigh) it seemed like a quick way to figure out WHAT was going on given the limited amount of other information